# Macro to switch bold on and off in table cells

Tags: tables, macros, conditionals, cals

I have start looking at the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), so my examples are connected to that packages. However, my questions are general, applicable under other environments, too.

In the documentation ([this TUGboat article](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cals/tb101parashchenko.pdf)) the author has defined a handy macro to switch on and off colour in cells:

```
\def\c{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty      % Colour switch (on of)
     \def\cals@bgcolor{gray}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}
```

It seems that a prerequisite for this macro, is that `cals@bgcolor{}` is defined. If not defined, the first instance you use the macro, you have to execute it twice before it works as I expected (turning on the defined colour).

*How do I extend the macro to test for both an undefined(?) and an empty value?*

The macro is used before and after a cell, or a range of cells (and/or rows):

```
\brow
      \c\cell{G}\c
      \cell{H}
      \c\cell{I}\c
\erow
```

It switch on colour for cell G, turn colour off for cell H, on for cell I and off before the next row.

I managed to extent the macro to switch off and on cell borders:

```
\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Border switch (on of)
     \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}
```

and padding:

```
\def\rp{\ifdim\cals@paddingR=0.0pt\relax    % Right padding switch (off-on)
    \cals@setpadding{Ag}
\else \setlength{\cals@paddingR}{0pt}\fi}
```

I tried to implement the same solution for bold (to turn on and off bold or other attributes, on a cell). However, I was not able to find how to test if `\bfseries` already was set.

```
\def\b{\ifx\<bold>\<false>  % Is \bfseries on or off?
     \bfseries              % If its off, turn it on
\else \mdseries\fi}         % If its on, turn it off
```

*How do I write this macro to test if bold on, and if the condition is false, turn bold on. If the conditions is true, `\mdseries` should be turned on?*

Comment: For the first part of the question: use `\ifdefined`. The second part I do not understand.

Comment: @marmot See my updated question. Is in more understandable what I want to achieve?

Comment: \c is already defined, the redefinition breaks `ç`, \b is also defined. Never use \def like this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use at least two letters "in real life". The \c-macro comes from the cals documentation. However, the ideas behind shortcuts is to reduce the number of keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current font series is stored in `\f@series`, you can test if it contains a b (which would mean bold):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\switchbold{}
{
  \tl_if_in:cnTF { f@series } {b}
   {
    \mdseries
   }
   {
    \bfseries
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

blblblb \switchbold bold \switchbold not bold
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mention both, `\f@size` and `\f@series`. Was it an intention or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @MarianG. that was a typo, thanks.